# OpenGL -- What is the most efficient way to draw an oval in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, graphics, geometry

I have been using TRIANGLE_FAN and drawing like 90 triangles. What's a better way?

Comment: Do you change the oval dynamically? I don't see what is slow about computing the vertices for 90 triangles once and draw them from a VBO.

Comment: The size of the oval changes, as does it position/translation. It's not slow, I was just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this page [drawing](http://basic4gl.wikispaces.com/2D+Drawing+in+OpenGL). It explain 2 different methods.

EDIT:

I was forgetting about nurbs. You could also use them . Have a look [here](http://www.jch.com/NURBS/index.html)

Comment: Thanks guy. You have a lower score than Jim so I picked your answer. That's how I roll.

Comment: NURBS are not directly supported by OpenGL. At some point curves or curve patches need to be tesselated to be processable by OpenGL. Either in the client program, or in a geometry or tesselation shader.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty much it, you can adjust that 90 up or down to your liking (or make it dependent on how big it is on-screen, or you could go the route of a [geometry shader](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader).

If you are ok with it not being geometry-based, just create a texture that is in the shape of an oval, and apply it to a quad.